# How come zum is the right usage here?

Tags: english-to-german, preposition, standard-german

I came across this line:

> Teilen der Stadt fielen einem Erdbeben zum Opfer.

which means :

> Parts of the city fell victim to an earthquake.

I understand, English and German cannot always be same in terms of preposition usage and order.
But, in this example I think *zum* is more suitable for *Erdbeben*. What is the logic behind using *zum* before *Opfer*? Are there anymore examples, wherein we can understand when to use *zum*?

(I only know that we should use "*zu + dem*" as "to" to show some destination place, *e.g.*: *zum Markt, zum Krankenhaus*.
Otherwise, *Infinitiv + zu* and *um ... zu*)

Comment: BTW, it should be _**Teile** der Stadt_.

Answer (score 8):

The German expression works differently from the English one:

> to fall victim to [event]

translates to

> [Ereignis] zum Opfer fallen

Thus, the occurrences of "to"/"zu" in these phrases are something like "structural false friends", as they denote a different element of the expression.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the difference? One is the subject and one is the object. The subject is the victim.

Comment: @Olafant *victim* is not the object nor the subject in any of the sentences. Indeed the verb has no object, it is rather a modifier (it explains "how" the falling happens)

Answer (score 2):

"zum" is not limited to a place, but it is similar to "to" as in your example

see also "zum Tode verurteilen", to sentence **to** death
"jemanden den Wölfen zum Fraß vorwerfen", to throw someone **to** the wolves to eat

an a little bit more idiomatic "dem Rotstift zum Opfer fallen" which means to be canceled due **to** lack of money